# How to check string length in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I check the length of in String in JavaScript? Here is a small code example:

```
if(value != null && value != "" && value.length !== 10 && !value.match(/^\d*$/)){

   // do something

}
```

The expression 'value.length !== 10' doesn´t work. A String must contain at least 10 characters. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "at least 10" means value.length >= 10. You are checking for exactly 10 and besides your check is !== "not equal value or not equal type" which in your case is useless.

Comment: value.trim().length >= 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `match`, `test` can be used with proper regex `\d{10,}`.

```
if (value && /^\d{10,}$/.test(value.trim()))
```

Comment: And if I need exactly 10 characters? What is the correct expression?

Comment: @Marwief `\d{10}` the `,` after `10` says that at least 10 characters(digits here), you can remove `,` to match exact 10 characters

Answer (score 4):

To Get the string length of a value for example:

```
var value="This is a string";
var string_length=value.length;
/*The string length will result to 16*/
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^\d*$/),
    value = $.trim("1234567890");

if (value.length >= 10 && regex.exec(value)) {
   // correct
} else {
   // incorrect
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.